# Pyspark - Unexpected Behavior of Spark Joins with AQE and SortMergeJoin

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm encountering an unexpected behavior while running a join operation in Spark.

```
df_joined = df_transactions.join(df_customers, how='inner', on='cust_id')
df_joined.write.format('noop').mode('overwrite').save('/FileStore/tables/trans_cust_join.parquet')
```

Here is the data that I am using:

```
df_transactions.show(5, False)
```

```
+----------+----------+----------+---------------+----------+----+-----+---+-------------+------+-----------+
|cust_id   |start_date|end_date  |txn_id         |date      |year|month|day|expense_type |amt   |city       |
+----------+----------+----------+---------------+----------+----+-----+---+-------------+------+-----------+
|C0YDPQWPBJ|2010-07-01|2018-12-01|TZ5SMKZY9S03OQJ|2018-10-07|2018|10   |7  |Entertainment|10.42 |boston     |
|C0YDPQWPBJ|2010-07-01|2018-12-01|TYIAPPNU066CJ5R|2016-03-27|2016|3    |27 |Motor/Travel |44.34 |portland   |
|C0YDPQWPBJ|2010-07-01|2018-12-01|TETSXIK4BLXHJ6W|2011-04-11|2011|4    |11 |Entertainment|3.18  |chicago    |
|C0YDPQWPBJ|2010-07-01|2018-12-01|TQKL1QFJY3EM8LO|2018-02-22|2018|2    |22 |Groceries    |268.97|los_angeles|
|C0YDPQWPBJ|2010-07-01|2018-12-01|TYL6DFP09PPXMVB|2010-10-16|2010|10   |16 |Entertainment|2.66  |chicago    |
+----------+----------+----------+---------------+----------+----+-----+---+-------------+------+-----------+
```

```
df_customers.show(5, False)
```

```
+----------+-------------+---+------+----------+-----+-----------+
|cust_id   |name         |age|gender|birthday  |zip  |city       |
+----------+-------------+---+------+----------+-----+-----------+
|C007YEYTX9|Aaron Abbott |34 |Female|7/13/1991 |97823|boston     |
|C00B971T1J|Aaron Austin |37 |Female|12/16/2004|30332|chicago    |
|C00WRSJF1Q|Aaron Barnes |29 |Female|3/11/1977 |23451|denver     |
|C01AZWQMF3|Aaron Barrett|31 |Male  |7/9/1998  |46613|los_angeles|
|C01BKUFRHA|Aaron Becker |54 |Male  |11/24/1979|40284|san_diego  |
+----------+-------------+---+------+----------+-----+-----------+
```

The datasets can be downloaded from this [repo](https://github.com/afaqueahmad7117/spark-experiments/tree/main/data/data_skew/).

And I have set the `spark.conf.set('spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold', -1)` in order to prevent spark from performing a broadcast join.

But when I run this query and see the query plan, I see that spark has performed `BroadcastHashJoin`.

What's intersting is that for the smaller dataset, spark has first performed repartition the dataset from 1 partition into 200 partitions, and then `AQE` optimization kicked in which in turn again repartitioned the data into 1 partition in order to perform `BroadcastHashJoin` as shown below:

[image]

My questions are:

- Why `SortMergeJoin` was not performed in the first place?
- And if spark was to perform `BroadcastHashJoin`, then why did it do repartitioning 2 times as data was already in 1 partition upon reading? Is it because `AQE` kicked in later and as part of further optimization, and it tried to do a `BroadcastHashJoin` instead of `SortMergeJoin`?

Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is going to pretty dependent on the data that you're using. Could you tell us how we can create your input data? Or if you can't share your data, could you recreate a representative example that we can reproduce and has the same behaviour?

Comment: @Koedlt, if I am working on samples of the given datasets, Spark is behaving in normal way where it just performs `SortMergeJoin`. The problem is occuring only while reading whole datasets. I have edited my question to give example of datasets and also I have provided [link](https://github.com/afaqueahmad7117/spark-experiments/tree/main/data/data_skew) to the datasets that I am using.

Comment: Sort Merge join is preferred when you use a fixed number of sample data in both the datasets. But, when you use the entire dataset, spark will choose the best join strategy based on the size of the data, even if you set autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1. One of your datasets might be smaller in size compared to the other and hence Broadcast join was preferred.

Comment: @Janani,  sure but even if `BroadcastHashJoin` was to be performed, I am wondering why did repartitioning of smaller dataset take place? Spark first performed `hashPartitioning` of the smaller dataset into 200 partitions, which again was repartitioned this into 1 partition to perform `BroadCastHashJoin`. And if I see `initial plan` under `physical plan`, it intended to do `SortMergeJoin`. But because of AQE, it performed `BroadcastHashJoin`.

Comment: Have you tried disabling broadcast for AQE specifically, setting to -1 [`spark.sql.adaptive.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-sql-configuration)

Comment: Yes, setting `spark.sql.adaptive.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` to -1 is working. This is performing`SortMergeJoin`. Thank you so much.

Comment: Cool, thanks for confirming!